# SQL Binding error

Tags: sql-server, binding

In SQL Server 2008, the following query works fine:

```
    WITH T AS (
        SELECT  node.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)') AS Name, node.value('(.)', 'float') AS Value
        FROM    @xml.nodes('data//*') AS x(node)
    )
    SELECT  @OutOfBounds = Count(T.Name)
    FROM    T INNER JOIN [int].RankItems ON [int].RankItems.RankItem = T.Name
    WHERE   (T.Value < [int].RankItems.[Min] OR T.Value > [int].RankItems.[Max])
    OPTION  (OPTIMIZE FOR (@XML UNKNOWN))
```

However, I wanted to write it as follows:

```
    WITH T AS (
        SELECT  node.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)') AS Name, node.value('(.)', 'float') AS Value
        FROM    @xml.nodes('data//*') AS x(node)
    )
    SELECT  @OutOfBounds = Count(T.Name)
    FROM    T INNER JOIN [int].RankItems T2 ON T2.RankItem = T.Name
    WHERE   (T.Value < T2.[Min] OR T.Value > T2.[Max])
    OPTION  (OPTIMIZE FOR (@XML UNKNOWN))
```

This gives me a "could not bind" error on T2. I can't see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the AS statement, ie

```
FROM    T INNER JOIN [int].RankItems AS T2 ON T2.RankItem = T.Name
```

Comment: Wow, so simple an omission in an otherwise un-simple query! Thank @RLT.